# GTX 760 video card is not being detected

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have a [GTX 760](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications) plugged on my [ASRock H87 Pro4](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H87%20Pro4/?cat=Specifications) on the `PCI Express 3.0` slot. The pins on the front of the board are connected.

I am on Windows 8 and the device is not showing up at all on the device manager. If I try to plug the monitor on the card I get no signal. If I try to install the driver I get a message saying that a device could not be found.

Searching on Google I found similar cases, but I am not sure how to fix it... What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, try reinserting the card and connect every external power connector.

Are you using the HDMI port? If yes try using VGA or DVI as HDMI connection needs appropriate drivers.

Comment: Turns out the power was just not fully plugged.